# When is it possible to determine the value of the expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this statement:

You can determine the value of $\frac{3}{4t+6}$ if:

$i) \sqrt{\frac{3}{4t+6}} = \frac{1}{2}$

$ii) 2t+3=6$

My attempt was:

With $i)$ I got $|\frac{3}{4t+6}| = \pm \frac{1}{4}$, So i can't get the value.

With $ii)$ I get the value of $t$, then i can get the value.

My answer was *Only with  $ii)$*, but the correct answer must be *Each one by itself.* So, $i)$ allow to get the value of the expression. What is wrong with my development?

I think that my error is that roots with even index are defined to be the positive value, per example $\sqrt{9} = 3$ and not $\sqrt{9} \neq -3$. Or similar argument is that root with even index are defined for positive values, therefore $\frac{3}{4t+6} > 0$, thus i need to get the positive value.

Is that my error? Or there are another error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the second. Observe that $4t+6=2(2t+3)=12$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, that is your mistake. If $\sqrt{u} = a$ you can definitely imply/conclude that $u=a^2$.

You got confused with the following (different) situation. If $u^2 = a$ (for some $a>0$) then you cannot infer if $u=\sqrt{a}$ or $u=-\sqrt{a}$, you're just not sure. Any of these two values works for $u$.